# ArrayFormula + Filter

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I'm creating a formula to filter 3 variables, so look for row X column 1 in this result.

So far so good.

But when I'm implementing this in arrayformula it's not working with Filter+ArrayFormula

```
={"Ped",
ARRAYFORMULA(IFERROR(IFS(
$A$2:$A="","",
$L$2:$L="","-",
$A$2:$A<>"",INDEX(ARRAYFORMULA(FILTER(Mensagens!$A:$D,TRIM(Mensagens!$B:$B)=$E$2:$E,TRIM(Mensagens!$D:$D)=$G$2:$G,TRIM(Mensagens!$C:$C)=$I$2:$I)),$F$2:$F,1)
),"-"))}
```

Comment: Wiring a first well-received question on SO is hard. You might want to add some information, of what you already tried to narrow down the problem. In your case, you present a formula in your question. For example, did you try to execute the formular by itself or in an isolated environment. In addition, some test data might be helpful for other user to better understand your problem. When posting a question with basically "it does not work", other users will have a harder time to invest in your question and be able to help you.

Answer (score 0):

try:

```
={"Ped"; ARRAYFORMULA(IFERROR(
 IF(A2:A="";;
 IF(L2:L=""; "-"; 
 FILTER(Mensagens!A:A; 
 REGEXMATCH(E2:E; TEXTJOIN("|"; 1; TRIM(Mensagens!B:B)));
 REGEXMATCH(G2:G; TEXTJOIN("|"; 1; TRIM(Mensagens!D:D)));
 REGEXMATCH(I2:I; TEXTJOIN("|"; 1; TRIM(Mensagens!C:C)))); )); "-"))}
```

### update:

```
={"Ped"; ARRAYFORMULA(IFERROR(
 IF(A2:A="";;
 IF(M2:M=""; "-"; VLOOKUP(F2:F&H2:H&J2:J; 
 {TRIM(Mensagens!B:B)&TRIM(Mensagens!D:D)&TRIM(Mensagens!C:C)\
 Mensagens!A:A}; 2; 0))); "-"))}
```

[image]

Comment: Didn't work for me 
Thanks @player0

Comment: @CésarEtaCardosodeAlmeida can you share a copy of your sheet?

Comment: Here it is 
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1YXvYlmB6RUYTHjIYPlbQGq-jE8AOgTQ3ijAqsxrjMQA/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: what should that formula do? can you provide some background?

Comment: The previous formula searches inside the filter obtained from column F, H and J. Bringing me the date of this comparison.

But emails have more than one try, so the index

Comment: @CésarEtaCardosodeAlmeida answer updated. see your sheet

Comment: I'm trying to use your formula but I need the Try variable (Column G)